# How to add an ID for each object inside JSON array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

There are many objects in the JSON file that look like I have shown below. I want to give an index number starting from `0` for each of these objects. How can I do it?

```
[
  {
    "language": "Python",
    "created": "2018-8-27 14:50:31",
    "evaluated": true,
    "hiddenCode": false
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: What is the reason for adding the IDs to unique Json keys? I don't see the use of an ID as you can access the value with the object key itself.

Comment: exactly what I want to do is to give each object a place called "index" and start the value of this "index" from 0

Comment: iterating the object with **object.keys** would be helpful for you.
`Object.keys(objectName).forEach((each, index) => {/* Your code */})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters#Parameters)) to get new, indexed, array.

```js
var array = [{
  "language": "Python1",
  "created": "2018-8-27 14:50:31",
  "evaluated": true,
  "hiddenCode": false
}, {
  "language": "Python2",
  "created": "2018-8-27 14:50:31",
  "evaluated": true,
  "hiddenCode": false
}]

const indexed = array.map((item, index) => Object.assign(item, { index }))

console.log(indexed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop on the objects and add new property,

```js
var array =[   {
        "language": "Python1",
        "created": "2018-8-27 14:50:31",
        "evaluated": true,
        "hiddenCode": false
    },  {
        "language": "Python2",
        "created": "2018-8-27 14:50:31",
        "evaluated": true,
        "hiddenCode": false
    }
];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
 array[i]["index "] =i;
}
console.log(array);
```

Comment: I have set this to my own file, but it prints the total number of index numbers, ie each index is output as 39  => "index":39 for each

Comment: @jennifercryt: can you add your code so that i can check what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this if you use ES,

You should use map to iterate over your objects and add the property in it

```js
var yourObjects =[   {
        "language": "Python1",
        "created": "2018-8-27 14:50:31",
        "evaluated": true,
        "hiddenCode": false
    },  {
        "language": "Python2",
        "created": "2018-8-27 14:50:31",
        "evaluated": true,
        "hiddenCode": false
    }
];

var i = 0;    
 yourObjects.map(
     (obj) => {
          obj['index'] = i;
          i++
          return obj;
     });
console.log(yourObjects);
```

Comment: `.map` callback function also receives `index` as a second argument, so no need for extra `var i`